# On the definition of the associated Legendre polynomials

Tags: polynomials, special-functions

*Mathematica* computes for n = 1,2,...:

```
(-1)^n (LegendreP[n, -1, -3]/Sqrt[2])
```

> ```
> -I, -3 I, -11 I, -45 I, -197 I, ...
> ```

*Maple* computes for n = 1,2,...:

```
(-1)^n*LegendreP(n, -1, -3)/sqrt(2)
```

> ```
> 1, 3, 11, 45, 197, ...
> ```

Question: Is there a bug or just different definitions?

**Edit:** Which one conforms with the (standard) definition in the *Handbook of Mathematical Functions* respectively with the definition in [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/14)?

Comment: See MathWorld (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AssociatedLegendrePolynomial.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, they have different definitions:

- Maple

[image: Legendre function in Maple]

- Mathematica

[image: Legendre function in Mathematica]

- Wikipedia

$$P_\ell^m(x)=(-1)^m \left(1-x^2\right)^{m/2} \frac{\mathrm d^m}{\mathrm dx^m} P_\ell(x)$$

This difference produces different complex phases (different branches of the square root).

Comment: @SophiaAntipolis It seems to me that DLMF corresponds to *Mathematica*: http://dlmf.nist.gov/14.6

Answer (score 5):

Something ybeltukov forgot to mention: `LegendreP[]` takes a third *optional* parameter corresponding to the "type" of Legendre function needed. There are three types, all agreeing within the unit disk, but having different branch cut structures outside it. By default, the type 1 function is computed: `LegendreP[n, m, z] == LegendreP[n, m, 1, z]`.

In particular, Maple's choice of type corresponds to [type 3](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/LegendreP3General) in *Mathematica*'s convention. Thus:

```
Table[(-1)^n LegendreP[n, -1, 3, -3]/Sqrt[2], {n, 5}]
   {1, 3, 11, 45, 197}
```

P.S. Similar remarks hold for `LegendreQ[]`.